# How should I read words and put them into vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17

So the user needs to input the number of words and then input the words themselves. How should I read these words and put them into a vector ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    vector<string>words;
    string word;

    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        cin >> word;
        words.push_back(word);
    }
    cout << words;
}
```

I've tried this but when I run it it gives me an error saying "no match for 'operator<<' " , it's something to do with cout << words; Could any of you please explain this error as well ?

Comment: The problem is not reading the words... is printing them. The `operator <<` is not defined for vectors. Try using another `for` for printing the words

Comment: Unrelated Standard Library trick: https://ideone.com/xqOgUW . Reads all of an input stream as words into a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is coming not from reading the words, but from printing them on this line:

```
cout << words;
```

There is no overload of `operator<<` for `std::cout` that takes a `std::vector<std::string>`. You need to write the loop yourself:

```
for (auto const & word : words)
  std::cout << word << " ";
```

---

Also, please don't use `using namespace std;`. And the correct header for `std::string` is `<string>`, not `<string.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to loop through the vector and display the words one by one.
This means using:

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
  cout << words[i] << endl;
```

It's a syntax error to cout a vector like that.

Comment: Is not a syntax error, the syntax is pretty ok. May be is a semantic error... there not exists the "function" called.